# How to find the name of the root node of a given xml file

Tags: c#

Im using c#.net windows form application. I have a xml file whose name is hello.xml and it goes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<languages>
  <language>
    <key>abc</key> 
    <value>hello how ru</value> 
  </language>
  <language>
    <key>def</key> 
    <value>i m fine</value> 
  </language>
  <language>
    <key>ghi</key> 
    <value>how abt u</value> 
  </language>
</languages>
```

How can i get the root node i.e `<languages>` into a text box. At this time I will have the xml file name. i.e `"hello.xml"`.  Using this I should get the root node.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of the xml.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using LINQ to XML you can do this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
string rootLocalName = doc.Root.Name.LocalName;
textBox1.Text = '<' + rootLocalName + '>';
```

With XmlDocument you can use this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("input.xml");
string rootName = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*").Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the `XmlDocument DocumentElement` property as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498423/how-do-i-get-the-xml-root-node-with-c):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("hello.xml");
string root = doc.DocumentElement.Name;
textBox1.Text = "<" + root + ">";
```