# How do I get the XML root node with C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I know that it's possible to get any XML node using C# if you know the node name, but I want to get the root node so that I can find out the name. Is this possible?

**Update**: I'm using XMLTextReader to read in the URL of a file and then loading that into XMLDocument object. Basically I'm trying to avoid LINQ to XML, but if there's another, better way then I'm always a good student.

Comment: How are you getting the XML document?

Comment: What you are using to parse XML?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Root node is the `DocumentElement` property of `XmlDocument`

```
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
```

If you only have the node, you can get the root node by

```
XmlElement root = xmlNode.OwnerDocument.DocumentElement
```

Comment: Thanks. I shall try that. Also, if the root of XmlDocument is .DocumentElement does that mean any children of root will be root.DocumentElement?

Comment: No, .DocumentElement is only a property of XmlDocument, while children of root are xmlNode, so they don't have this property. That's why you use .OwnerDocument to get the root.

Comment: Amazing answer! I can't thank you enough @CharlesB for saving me! Wish I could upvote this multiple times.

Answer (score 27):

I got the same question here.  If the document is huge, it is not a good idea to use XmlDocument. The fact is that the first element is the root element, based on which XmlReader can be used to get the root element.  Using XmlReader will be much more efficient than using XmlDocument as it doesn't require load the whole document into memory.

```
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(<your_xml_file>)) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
      // first element is the root element
      if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) {
        System.Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Excellent! Very concise and efficient.

Answer (score 17):

Agree with Jewes, XmlReader is the better way to go, especially if working with a larger XML document or processing multiple in a loop - no need to parse the entire document if you only need the document root.

Here's a simplified version, using XmlReader and MoveToContent().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.movetocontent.aspx

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(p_fileName))
{
  if (xmlReader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element)
    rootNodeName = xmlReader.Name;
}
```

Comment: Please say what it means if the `if` statement fails.

Comment: If the if never hits then the file content has no elements. It will read to the end of the file and rootNodeName will not be set.

Comment: That is correct.

To take it further you can have problems with parsing the XML in the first place, cause it's not well-formed or maybe has a DTD declaration (which btw you can disable using XmlReaderSettings - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2adhb2f(v=VS.100).aspx) etc. so you should probably wrap the whole parsing with a try-catch, just in case, but that would be a different subject really, and yes test for a blank or null root node name (String.IsNullOrEmpty() method).

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
string rootNode = XmlDoc.ChildNodes[0].Name;
```

Comment: @nesomis Thank you - your answer was helpful to me.  Minor note:  ChildNodes is a property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XElement root = XDocument.Load(fStream).Root;
```

Comment: Huh? It returns `XDocument`. `public static XDocument Load(Stream stream);` -System.Xml.Linq.XDocument (System.Xml.Linq.dll)