# Read first root node from XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I work with three kinds  of XML files  :

Type A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc versao="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
</nfeProc>
```

Tyepe B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cancCTe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="1.04">
</cancCTe>
```

Type C:]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cteProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="1.04">
</cteProc>
```

I have try with this code to read the first node :

```
     XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
     xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\crruopto\135120068964590_v01.04-procCTe.xml");
     XmlNodeList ml = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("*");
     XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
     exti = root.ToString();
```

but dont return anything  i want to read the first node , need to know if the file is nfeProc ,canCTE or cteProc
The second question is how i get the value from "value" in the same tag???

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498423/how-do-i-get-the-xml-root-node-with-c) post:

```
//Root node is the DocumentElement property of XmlDocument

XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement

//If you only have the node, you can get the root node by

XmlElement root = xmlNode.OwnerDocument.DocumentElement
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using XPath. Here's an example where I read in the XML content from a locally stored string and select whatever the first node under the root is:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(new StringReader(xml));

XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("(/*)");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't required to use the `XmlDocument` stuff, then `Linq` is your friend.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\crruopto\135120068964590_v01.04-procCTe.xml");
XElement first = doc.GetDescendants().FirstOrDefault();
if(first != null)
{
  //first.Name will be either nfeProc, canCTE or cteProc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with Linq to XML is the newest and most powerful way of working with XML in .NET and offers you a lot more power and flexibility than things like XmlDocument and XmlNode.

Getting the root node is very simple:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\crruopto\135120068964590_v01.04-procCTe.xml");
Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Name.ToString());
```

Once you have constructed an XDocument you don't need to use any LINQ querying or special checking. You simply pull the Root property from the XDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i have solved this way the first part

```
   XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDoc.Load(nomear);
   XmlNodeList ml = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("*");
   XmlNode primer = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
   exti = primer.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to be clear, you're asking about the root *element*, not the root *node*.

You can use an XmlReader to avoid having to load large documents completely into memory. See my answer to a how to find the root element at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60642354/1307074.

Second, once the reader is referencing the element, you can use the reader's `Name` property to get the qualified tag name of the element. You can get the value as a string using the `Value` property.