# Getting the name of an XML document's root node

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have an XML file that I want to load. I want to put a condition in my code to check and make sure the root node is 'TimeLog'. If it isn't then tell the user that they picked the wrong XML file.

In the code below, r.Name only returns an empty string. I'd expect it to return "TimeLog" but it does not.

```
    private void loadFromFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(File.Exists("TimeLog.xml"))
        {
            XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("TimeLog.xml");
            r.MoveToContent();
            r.ReadStartElement();
            if (r.Name == "TimeLog") //The current value or r.name is "".
            {
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        r.ReadToDescendant("EntryName");
                        String name = r.ReadInnerXml();
                        r.ReadToFollowing("StartDateTime");
                        String start = r.ReadInnerXml();
                        r.ReadToFollowing("EndDateTime");
                        String end = r.ReadInnerXml();
                        r.ReadToFollowing("Duration");
                        String dur = r.ReadInnerXml();

                        entries.Add(new Entry(name, start, end, dur));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This is not a TimeLog XML file", "This is not a TimeLog XML file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
            r.Close();
        }
    }
```

The XML file is the output my saveToFile() function and looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TimeLog>
    <Entry>
        <EntryName>Entry 01</EntryName>
        <StartDateTime>8/21/2015 8:50:40 PM</StartDateTime>
        <EndDateTime>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</EndDateTime>
        <Duration>00:00:00</Duration>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <EntryName>Entry 02</EntryName>
        <StartDateTime>8/21/2015 8:50:40 PM</StartDateTime>
        <EndDateTime>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</EndDateTime>
        <Duration>00:00:00</Duration>
    </Entry>
</TimeLog>
```

How can I check to make sure the name of the Root Node is "TimeLog" without calling another .Read() function and throwing the order off for the code in the while statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description of the `ReadStartElement` method:

> Checks that the current node is an element and advances the reader to
>   the next node.

Next node is `XmlNodeType.Whitespace`.

---

Consider the following XML:

```
<TimeLog>
    <Entry>
```

Also it can be written as:

```
<TimeLog>    <Entry>
```

There is `XmlNodeType.Whitespace` between two `XmlNodeType.Element`.

`MoveToContent` sets reader to the root node - TimeLog. Then `ReadStartElement` reads TimeLog and moves to the whitespace.

---

There is no space in the following view:

```
<TimeLog><Entry>
```

---

Btw, you can use `ReadToFollowing` method:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml"))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("TimeLog");
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: I'm still new to XML, why would the next node be Whitespace? The only whitespace that I recognize is the text in between the tags.

Comment: I did not realize the indentation characters would actually be read, I assumed whitespace would be ignored. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the below code and let me know if any errors still:

```
if(File.Exists("TimeLog.xml"))
    {
        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("TimeLog.xml");
        r.MoveToContent();
  //Here check whether there exist a root element and then also check itsname.
  //If this doesn't work out then put the r.Name=="TimeLog" inside While loop and then see.

    if (r.IsStartElement() && string.Equals(r.Name, "TimeLog"))
        {
            while (r.Read())
            {
                if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    r.ReadToDescendant("EntryName");
                    String name = r.ReadInnerXml();
                    r.ReadToFollowing("StartDateTime");
                    String start = r.ReadInnerXml();
                    r.ReadToFollowing("EndDateTime");
                    String end = r.ReadInnerXml();
                    r.ReadToFollowing("Duration");
                    String dur = r.ReadInnerXml();

                    entries.Add(new Entry(name, start, end, dur));
                }//End of inner If
            }//End of While
        }//End of Outer second IF
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is not a TimeLog XML file", "This is not a TimeLog XML file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }//End of Else
        r.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly with my existing code.

Comment: @Bill.. Good to hear this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LINQ to XML, check `XDocument.Root.Name`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("TimeLog.xml");

if (doc.Root.Name == "TimeLog")
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is not a TimeLog XML file", "This is not a TimeLog XML file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root *element* can be found very quickly using the following code. By using an XmlReader rather than an XmlDocument, the entire document does not have to be loaded in memory.

```
  if (File.Exists("TimeLog.xml"))
  {
    XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("TimeLog.xml");
    while (reader.Read() && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) ;
    // r is now referencing the node for the root element.
  }
```

The root *node* in a valid XML document is an XML declaration, which is probably not what you want.