# How can I access the Root property of the XmlDocument object?

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to query an XMLDocument and receiving an error:

```
var query = from date in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Serial")
```

The error is about `Root`.

My full code looks something like this:

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    StorageFile xmlFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Content‌​1.xml"); 
    XmlDocument xmlDoc; 
    xmlDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xmlFile); 
    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument duc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.GetXml()); 
    var query = from Date in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Serial")
        where Date.Attribute("No").Value == "1";
}
```

How can I access the `Root` property of the `XmlDocument` object?

Comment: Please be more precise

Comment: Xml parsing requires:using System.Xml

Comment: i used System.Xml still its showing error

Comment: Your `xmlDoc` object is of type `XmlDocument`, and [XmlDocument does not have a property called Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument_properties.aspx). To access the root of an `XmlDocument`, [use the DocumentElement property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4498446/302677)

Comment: @Rachel - have you vote to reopen this question? )

Comment: @MikroDel Yes, you can click on the "Edited X hours/days ago" link at the bottom of the question to view the question revisions, which includes the post getting closed or reopened

Comment: @Rachel - thanks for the information! =) Have you done it after this post of me? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174735/closed-as-not-a-real-question

Comment: @MikroDel Yes, your meta post was what brought this question to my attention :)

Answer (score 4):

Your `xmlDoc` object is of type `XmlDocument`, and [XmlDocument does not have a property called Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument_properties.aspx).

To access the root of an `XmlDocument`, use the [DocumentElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement.aspx) property

```
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
```

It should be noted `DocumentElement` is of type [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx), and `XmlElement` does not contain a property called `Elements`, so you'll need to look up the alternative to that property if you choose to stick with `XmlDocument`

But in your case, you are probably getting `XmlDocument` mixed up with the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class, which *does* contain a property called `Root` of type [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx), and `XElement` contains an `Elements` property.

So either replace your `XmlDocument` with an `XDocument`, or rewrite your linq query to use the `XmlDocument` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to have these at the top of the file:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
```

If you are coding a Windows 8 "Immersive" app, add this:

```
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
```

Comment: i used all the above mentioned namespaces but still its showing error in the Root word

Comment: Did you add System.Xml as a Reference under the Assembly explorer?

Comment: thanks to everyone ..my problem got solved ..thank you very much :) :) :)