# How do you handle parsing XML in C# when the XML can refer to one of many objects?

Tags: c#, xml

I am receiving a status object which contains an XML response.

This response can be a 'Success' message, an 'Error' message or null (hasn't yet processed so there is no message).

I cannot think of an elegant way to parse this XML.

The only two options I can think of would be to TryParse the XML string on each of error messages, or perform a String.Contains("Success") or String.Contains("Error").

Of these two methods, the TryParse seems like the best... But still looks pretty ugly.

I would like to know if there are any better ways of handling this.

The receiving object can look like something like this:

```
public class ReturnedObject{
    public string MessageId
    public string MessageDescription
    public string XML
}
```

the XML can be either null or one of the samples below:

```
<Success>
    <paymentReference>123</paymentReference>
    <targetBankAccount>01-0002-3948</targetBankAccount>
</Success>
```

or

```
<Error>
    <errorMessage>Your bank account was invalid</errorMessage>
    <errorBelongsToField>BankNumber</errorBelongsToField>
</Error>
```

My current parser looks like:

```
        if (documentStatusResponse.Xml == null)
        {
            return disassociatedDocumentStatusResponse;
        }

        var root = XDocument.Parse(documentStatusResponse.Xml).Root;

        if (root != null)
        {
            if (root.Name == "Error")
            {
                disassociatedDocumentStatusResponse.Errors = _xmlExtractor.RetrieveStatusErrors(documentStatusResponse.Xml);
            }
            else if (root.Name == "Success")
            {
                disassociatedDocumentStatusResponse.Reconciliation =
                    _xmlExtractor.RetrieveStatusReconciliation(documentStatusResponse.Xml);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide samples of Xml you are trying to parse. And what is expected result of parsing?

Comment: If you could provide an example of your XML, it would make it a hell of alot easier to help. Also, what does your code look like?

Comment: XML is always in one format: XML.

Comment: I already know how to parse the XML - I am looking for an algorithm, not a concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an XML Library (Linq-XML in my example) to parse the root node, then pass the XML onto the a class that can parse it.

For example:

```
ParseMessage(string xml)
{
   XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
   String rootName = doc.Root.Name;

   if (rootName == "SuccessMessageName")
   {  
       //Depending if you deserialize from an XDocument...
       ProcessSuccessMessage(doc);
       // or String.
       ProcessSuccessMessage(xml);
   }
   else if (rootName == "ErrorMessageName")
       //etc.
}
```

Or, you can use one of these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498423/how-do-i-get-the-xml-root-node-with-c) to get the Root Element name that might be more optimal if you don't need the entire message as an `XDocument`.

Comment: +1 lol talk about progressive editing. It's almost like looking at real-time coding. :D

Comment: @eandersson Yeah, clicked way too soon, then it was just a matter of fix it quick :)

Comment: not a good solution when one of the inputs is a whole data set that you still have to deserialize

Comment: If the xml is null this will throw an error, Root also has the possibility of being null.

Comment: @SamuelDavis, true but error checking is often omitted for brevity on SO answers.

Comment: I used your solution in the code that I edited into my question. I was hoping there would be a nicer looking solution but can't find anything else out there. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I usually create one class structure that can take all possible XML inputs. If that's not possible - make the most general cut and pre-test your input for serializing it. It should be rare to have to do that and I've mostly had to do it when one of the inputs is not a well-formed XML.

If the root element is different you can wrap the whole input inside `<MyXML> .... </MyXML>` and now you have one known root element to deserialize