# Saving to xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a question about updating data in current xml file.

For example I want to change Radius to "50"

XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
    <Radius>25</Radius>
    <Length>40</Length>
    <Height>15</Height>
    <Name>Oks</Name>
</Settings>
```

I can read these settings with this code:

```
public void GetSettings()
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(location);

            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Settings");

            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                tb_height.Text = xn["Height"].InnerText;
                tb_lenght.Text = xn["Length"].InnerText;
                tb_radius.Text = xn["Radius"].InnerText;
                tb_name.Text = xn["Name"].InnerText;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `xml.Save(path)` - with opposite code in your foreach; i.e., set the value of `xn["nodename"]` to whatever the `tb_something.Text` value is.

Comment: Err...  What's the question?

Comment: Why you use `foreach`  loop?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it without foreach loop

Comment: `XmlNode xn = xml.SelectNodes("/Settings")Item(0);`

Comment: re:foreach... You're using SelectNodes() to select all nodes of type Settings, which returns a collection, you can, instead, select the root note directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498423/how-do-i-get-the-xml-root-node-with-c

Comment: XmlNode xn = xml.SelectNodes("/Settings").Item(0);
This is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you are trying to do.

but to save your file, you can simply:

```
xml.Save(PathToSaveTo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with

```
public void SaveSettings()
        {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(location);

            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Settings");

            XmlNode xn = xml.SelectNodes("/Settings").Item(0);

            xn["Height"].InnerText = tb_height.Text;
            xn["Length"].InnerText = tb_lenght.Text;
            xn["Radius"].InnerText = tb_radius.Text;
            xn["Name"].InnerText = tb_name.Text;

            xml.Save(location);
        }
```