# transform xml-file depending on root-tag

Tags: c#, xslt, xmlreader

I have an xml-file which I want to read. Depending on the root-tag I´m doing an xsl-transform before and read the modified file:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(myFile);

var root = new XmlDocument();
root.Load(reader);
if (root.DocumentElement.Name == "FC_FeatureCatalogue")
{
    var xsltDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xsltDoc.Load("myXslt.xsl"));

    XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings(false, true);
    var transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
    transformer.Load(xsltDoc, xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());

    using (var stream = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        transformer.Transform(reader, new XsltArgumentList(), stream);
    }
}
```

When the condition passes the file determined by `newFileName` is created. However it does contain only an empty entry. So I debugged a bit and noticed that when calling `root.Load(reader)` the file is read until EOF. This is why I assume when using the same file for the transformation the transformer simply does nothing as the reader has no further content.

So is there a way to re-set the reader (I know, `XmlReader` is ment to be "forward only") or alternativly get the root-tag of the original xml-file without reading to EOF and transform it?

EDIT: To verify my assumption I also added these lines within my `using`-block:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    reader.Close();
    reader = XmlReader.Create(myFile);
    transformer.Transform(reader, new XsltArgumentList(), stream);
}
```

Now the created file contains all the expected data. However I hope there´ll be a way to read the root-tag and transform the file without re-reding the whole file.

Comment: Try this :             XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(myFile);
            reader.MoveToContent();
            if (reader.Name == "FC_FeatureCatalogue") { }

Comment: @jdweng Yeap, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an approach that was inspired [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498423/how-do-i-get-the-xml-root-node-with-c). Actually I won´t need to read the entire document (as `XmlDocument.Load` does) to only get the root-element. So I simply read the readers first lines:

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) break;
}
if (reader.Name == "FC_FeatureCatalogue")
{
    // ...
}
```

Alternativly you may also use this as suggested by jdweng which is a bit shorter:

```
reader.MoveToContent();
if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) { ... }
```

Supprisingly to me is only that although the readers internal position is now somewhere within the document we can transform the xml appropriately. I guess this is because the elements read before are just "xml-chunk" like the xml-declaration or any comments.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a way to reset the stream within a XmlReader.

One approach would be to use a stream more directly, as follows.

```
  using (FileStream fs = File.Create(myFile))
  {
    var root = new XmlDocument();

    root.Load(fs);

    if (root.DocumentElement.Name == "FC_FeatureCatalogue")
    {
      var xsltDoc = new XmlDocument();
      xsltDoc.Load("myXslt.xsl"));

      XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings(false, true);
      var transformer = new XslCompiledTransform();
      transformer.Load(xsltDoc, xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());

      fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
      {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
          transformer.Transform(reader, new XsltArgumentList(), stream);
        }            
      }
    }
  }
```